# Run a Application besids my watch Application

Tags: python, bash, process, subprocess

i have written a codesnippet in my Python script that get executeted every 3(1) minutes that checks if a other Pythonscript(2) is currently running and if not it should start this and show the terminal output.But the first(1) script should continue. I tested folowing:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
os.system(bashCommand+" &")
```

whereas

```
bashCommand ="uxterm -fa 'Monospace' -fs 14 -e python /home/pi/Dokumente/streamWatch.py"
```

both stopped and probably waited for (2) to finish. How to solve this?

Thanks before-hand

Comment: @simon please tell me more than 2 words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a tool like `monit` or `supervisord`. It might take a few minutes to learn the tool, but it will be more robust and flexible than your custom solution.